# create "get started button" Facebook messenger on python

Tags: python, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am new to messenger platform, I did search a lot on the internet how to make a "get started" button on messenger in python but there is no answer.
Below is my code:

```
def send_get_started(bot,recipient_id):
button = {
    "get_started":{
        "payload" : "first_coming"
    }
}
bot.send_raw(button)
```

the **send_raw** function here I get from bot.py in pymessenger2 on python
[which is here](https://github.com/Cretezy/pymessenger2/blob/master/pymessenger2/bot.py) (also the code below)

```
def send_raw(self, payload):
    request_endpoint = '{0}/me/messages'.format(self.graph_url)
    response = requests.post(
        request_endpoint,
        params=self.auth_args,
        data=json.dumps(payload, cls=AttrsEncoder),
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    result = response.json()
    return result
```

Of course it did not work, I think I misunderstand somewhere, could somebody show me my problem?
Thanh you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint should be:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile

You could see this in the reference: [Get Started Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button)

Comment: could you please provide the code ? as I am facing the same problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is wrong. Your request is using the '/messages' path when it should be using '/thread_settings'

When setting the 'Get Started' button or the Greeting you need to use the endpoint

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/thread_settings

Comment: Thank you so much! It is true that I used the wrong endpoint.